# read any file to buffer

Tags: c#, file-handling

I am not new to C# but quite new to file handling. My current idea is to read files (of any kind, for example jpg, txt, pdf etc) to a buffer to be able to do something with it later, for example just write an exact copy to the same folder (for testing) or send it to another pc via network. I know that there is a specific method for sending files via network, but I'd like to be able to handle the file itself and understand how to open files the correct way and write them the correct way to have a working copy.

If I just open a file and use for example a StreamReader like this:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(sourcePath, GetEncoding(sourcePath)))
    {
        // Read the stream to a string, and write the string to the console.
        String line = sr.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(line);

        WriteFile(outputFile, GetEncoding(sourcePath), line);
    }
```

it will create a bigger file (for example of an jpg) which does not work in the end. I think it has something to do with the encoding, but since I have to little knowledge about files itself maybe someone can give me some helpful tips.

Comment: `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` are for text files (handling byte sequences<=>char mappings. See, you tried to use *Encoding*). Use FileStream instead for reading/writing binary data.

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Okay, understood :) and it works fine using the FileStream instead. Thank you very much!